# How to check if a printer is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp

I am about to purchase HP LaserJet Pro M15w Printer but the last time I bought an HP printer I had to return it because it wasn't compatible with Ubuntu.

Is there a way to check this first?

I have Samsung, and their Unified driver pretty much takes care of everything.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't really know, but from just my own experience, if the printer page has a [PPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description) file to download, then I am usually able to set it up.  You might want to also look for it [here](http://www.openprinting.org/printers).

Answer (score 0):

For Linux HP Drivers, see: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing

Please don't mix "Is my printer is compatible with Ubuntu?" with "will ubuntu recognize my printer out of the box without any effort?"

Most of the printers are compatible, but due to licensing issues, they require you to download the drivers from the hardware official site and ubuntu won't "automagically" recognize them.